# Index out of range error, array of custom objects. Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have index out of range error when i delete object from my array. There is my code. It is an Elevator function which takes object of Floor class and works with array of objects of Passenger class on this floor. I create a temporary copy of object of current floor and then I go along array of this copy and if object is suitable for the conditions we push this object to Elevator array of passengers and delete it by index from original array of current floor object. If this matters, I use the Equatable protocol and created a function to compare.
Thanks for any answers.

```
class Passenger: Equatable{...}

func ==(l: Passenger, r: Passenger) -> Bool {
  return l === r
} 

func checkFloor(f: Floor){
    var tempFloor = f
    var pass = passengers
    for i in 0..<passengers.count {
        if(passengers.isEmpty){
            break
        }
        if(pass[i].getFloor()==f.getIdFloor()){
            f.peoples.append(pass[i])
            f.peoples[f.peoples.count - 1].setDirection(who: "nothing")
            //if var index = passengers.index(of: pass[i]) {
            if let index = searchInArray(who: passengers, who: pass[i]) {
                passengers.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
    }
    // in this part I have a problem 
    for i in 0..<tempFloor.countOf() { 
        if(f.peoples.isEmpty || passengers.count >= capacity){
            break
        }
        if(tempFloor.peoples[i].getDirection()==tempFloor.peoplesDirection() 
        ){
            passengers.append(tempFloor.peoples[i])
            if let index = f.peoples.index(of: tempFloor.peoples[i]) {
                  if (index >= 0 && index < f.peoples.count) {
                      //print(index)
                      f.peoples.remove(at: index)  // index out of range error
                  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tempFloor.countOf() is same if i write tempFloor.peoples.count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing items whilst enumerating a range, so the range is changing (potentially often) but this wont update `for i in 0..<tempFloor.countOf()`

When you remove an item from an array, each item after that index changes its index and the count is reduced. so if you plan to do this, it's usually best to enumerate the array backwards, so the removal of the current item will not affect what your doing next.

To demonstrate, try this code in a playground

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for (index, item) in arr.enumerated().reversed() {
    if item % 2 == 0 {
        arr.remove(at: index)
    }
}

print(arr)
```

It will iterate over the items in the array backwards and remove any that are even, and will output:

> "[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]\n"